# Set a language for Google AutoML

Tags: classification, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have to train a model for classification in russian language using AutoML. Russian is supported language as Google says but there is no information how to change english to russian. Or should it happen automatically? Thank you!

Comment: Your question should be more descriptive so that the answerers can provide the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

The base model is trained on all of the languages described in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/languages), you don't need to set the language before training.  (unlike AWS)